# react-i18next v10 without hooks

Tags: react-hooks, react-i18next

I have been trying to implement react-i18next (10.9.0) by using the code from below link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/l23no88qmz?from-embed

But I got the error:

```
Attempted import error: 'translate' is not exported from 'react-i18next'.
```

From [ https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/810 ], I came to know that 'translate' was used in v8, and v10 uses hooks.

I wanted to know if I could use react-i18next (10.9.0) without hooks?
If yes, what should I use instead of 'translate'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-i18next` v10 has been specifically refactored to work with hooks, so you'll need to either adapt your code to support hooks, either use the legacy v9 version.

Comment: a nice guide can be found here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb/stats

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the hook as an prop and send it to the component.

```
import {useTranslation} from 'react-i18next';

class XXX extends React.Component {
    render() {
          const {i18nTranslation} = this.props;

          return <div>{i18nTranslation.t('welcome.msg')}</div>
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(function (props) {
     const i18nTranslation = useTranslation();
     return <XXX {...props} i18nTranslation={i18nTranslation} />
});
```